# Size of Meteor payload in large application

Tags: meteor

I have been trying out Meteor and so far so good! I have read that all html and javascript files are concatenated when sent to a client so my question is how does this scale when the app gets large, let's say 150+ pages, several complex ones (x3 for read/write/delete) and all the scripts & business logic that go along with the pages.

1. Am I right in thinking that the data sent to the client could be substantial?
2. Is it only sent the first time or every time when the browser is closed and re-opened (I don't mean the 'hot' updates sent while the client is connected).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It definitely can be a big initial payload, though this is mitigated by (as you said) minification and concatenation, as well as gzipping and caching the payload which are both also done.

With that number of pages, you could dynamically generate them from templates, with the content going over the wire after initial page load.

I have a few Meteor apps in production and the largest initial load for them runs 700kb, including javascript, css, fonts and images. 200k of that is javascript. It opens fast enough and once open, everything feels instantaneous.

That said, it really depends on your site and how it's designed.

Comment: Thanks for the info - what size (in terms of screen-count) is your app? I am trying to get a feel for how meteor will scale for a complex enterprise app

Comment: The site in question is an internal training app, which handles ~20  categories with ~10 screens per category. i18n support is implemented but translations have not been loaded, so this will eventually be 5 or 6x this amount. So say 1000, though there are really only 5 main templates (type of page) that pull in multiple helper templates, of which there are probably 4 or 5. All the page text throughout the site is stored in the database.